# Can't import ml.h in android opencv 2.3

Tags: android, opencv, compiler-errors, android-ndk, svm

I'm using the C interface, and I get the following error snipped when I run ndk-build when I include "ml.h":

```
In file included from /Users/user/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/stl_algobase.h:61,
             from /Users/user/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/bits/stl_tree.h:62,
             from /Users/user/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/map:60,
             from /Users/user/android-opencv/OpenCV-2.3.1/share/OpenCV/../../include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp:2022,
             from /Users/user/android-opencv/OpenCV-2.3.1/share/OpenCV/../../include/opencv/ml.h:46,
             from /Users/user/CarSafe/jni/blink_detection.c:7:
/Users/user/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/cstddef:51: error:   expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ':' token
```

If I comment out the include for "ml.h", it compiles fine and runs normally.

The problem is I want to use the opencv svm library in my C code. What am I doing wrong?  Or should I just compile it as C++ code and use the ml.hpp header within C++.  This works for other code in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at the last line of your output:

```
/Users/user/android-ndk-r7c/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/cstddef:51: error:   expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before ':' token
```

Based on what you wrote in your question it appears you are trying to use a C compiler to compile code using the C++ standard library.

Also, while I'm not familiar with OpenCV, I would assume you should be able to compile your code as C++ and still include "ml.h". C++ headers don't always use the *.hpp extension.